# How can i simultaneously download files from urls saved in a json file?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I am new to python development and currently doing a project on url scrapping. My project scrapes a website which provides apk files. I am able to scrape and download the apk files sequentially which takes quite a lot of time as each app is ~30MB in size.

Here's my code that I am currently running:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename) as appsFile:
    apps = json.load(appsFile)

for app in apps:
    if(apps[app]['download?'] == 'Y'):
        apk_download(apps[app]['package'], apps[app]['download_link'])
```

This is how my JSON file looks like:

```
{
    "app name": {
        "download_link": "download link here",
        "package": "app name here",
        "download?": "a Y or N here",
        "version": "downloaded app version here"
},...
```

apk_download() function is defined separately.

What i want to do is to be able to download atleast 3 files simultaneously. How can i achieve that in the above code? Or any other approach I need to try? I am using python3.